# SQL , Cross join alternative/faster solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

We have a simple table with two columns like

```
+-------+-------+
| fname | lname |
+-------+-------+
| foo   | bar   |
+-------+-------+
```

we also have another table which contains Months

```
+-------+
| month |
+-------+
| jan   |
| feb   |
| mar   |
+-------+
```

The goal is to get a table like:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| fname | lname | month |
+-------+-------+-------+
| foo   | bar   | jan   |
| foo   | bar   | feb   |
| foo   | bar   | mar   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

To get this table, I used a `cross join`, but the fetching time has increased exponentially when data are increased. This should be a simple duplication of data, and just the month column should be added at the end of each row, but it seems more complex behind the scenes. Can this query be run faster in any alternative way?

Comment: Does the SQL "plan" show the cross-join as the biggest cpu usage? eg, is there maybe a missing index or something?

Comment: Well you could store your data in the unnormalized format the expected output.  That would reduce the size of the execution plan.

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` *is* both what you want and need. If you are `CROSS JOIN`ing 1,000 to 1,000 rows (which is a tiny amount), you end up with 1,000,000 rows. Making cartesian products does exponentially get slower the more rows you need, because the number of rows you get is also exponentially increasing.

Comment: What you described is the perfect example for a cross join,. It shouldn't be a big deal unless you have huge tables.

Comment: If this is something you need to do often, then you may well want to do this as a one-off process first and index the table; then you have a single, one off, slow query, but then the `JOIN`s to the table afterwards (presumably to a much smaller subset) are much faster.

Comment: 1. `Insert Into table Select 'Jan', ftable.*`, then 2. `Insert into table Select 'Feb', ftable.*`, ...  Brute force might be faster.

Comment: Could sorting be the problem?

Answer (score -3):

data

```
CREATE TABLE table1(fname  varchar(100),lname varchar(100))
insert into table1
(fname,lname) values
('foo','bar');
CREATE TABLE table2(month    varchar(100))
insert into table2
(month) values
('jan'),
('feb'),
('mar');
```

the alternative way is using `Cross Apply` but it is slower than `Cross Join`

```
SELECT fname,
       lname,
       month
FROM   table2
       CROSS apply (SELECT *
                    FROM   table1
                    WHERE  1 = 1) A
```

if your first table has one row structure forget cross join and use `value` and `alias`

```
SELECT 'foo' fname,
       'bar' lname,
       month
FROM   table2
```

or

```
declare @fname varchar(100)=(select fname from table1)
declare @lname varchar(100)=(select lname from table1)
select @fname fname,
       @lname lname,
       month
FROM   table2
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L1FNXeoz)